# Applying multiple filters using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
data_live = data[data['MEDIA TYPE'] == "TV/OTT", "TV"]
```

I want to apply a filter  filters on "Media Type": TV and TV/OTT both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
data_live = data[data['MEDIA TYPE'].isin(["TV/OTT", "TV"])]
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you!